# How to calculate how many events are needed for a discovery?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, statistics

If I am searching for a new particle which is decaying into two photons. In the mass bin 500 - 530 GeV I find an excess of n= 685 events, where I estimated the background events bg = 600, and this gives sig = 85 signal events. I could calculate the significance Z using the Azimov formula:

$Z = \sqrt{2(n \cdot ln(1 + sig/bg) - sig )} = 3.4 $

Now I would like to know how much more data I would need to collect for a discovery, corresponding to Z = 5 sigma?

I'm really lost how to solve this, since I could transform the equation to $bg$ or $sig$ but then I would still miss a the other variable. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Perhaps you could assume your S/N is constant.

Answer (score 1):

It is not something this equation can tell you. If it could it would not be a discovery but a known process.

The background can, with a certain probability, produce statistical accumulations and the standard deviation gives a measure of how probable or not they are. To estimate how many events must be accumulated for the 3.4 sigma to become 5 or to disappear into the background, you have to fit a crossection to the 3.4 sigma and use a monte carlo for your background and signal and see how much total statistics should be accumulated. Monte Carlos are used because both the background and the possible signal depend on a large number of variables and a single formula cannot give you exact numbers. [Statistical testing](http://www.pp.rhul.ac.uk/~cowan/stat/cowan_munich16.pdf) is not simple . Consider that [the signal](https://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~dvandyk/Research/14-reviews-higgs.pdf) itself is in a probabilistic distribution.

This said, I found in page 75 of [this paper](https://www.ippp.dur.ac.uk/~ross/invisibles13/school/talks/GlenCowanStatisticalandDataAnalysis.pdf)   an analysis of the Asimov formula  for significance 5 versus the number of background only, compared to monte carlo expectation and it fits well.